# Loading ReactJS data issue

Tags: reactjs

I have this codo to load data

```
 const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8765/api/list-users.json`)
            .then((getData) => {
                setApiData(getData.data);
            })
    }, [])
```

And in using apiData in table

```
<Table.Body>
    {apiData.map((data) => {
        return (
            <Table.Row>
                <Table.Cell>{data.name}</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>{data.email}</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>
                    <Link to="/update">
                        <Button
                            color="green"
                            onClick={() =>
                                setData(data.name, data.email, data.password)
                            }
                        >
                            Update
                        </Button>
                    </Link>
                </Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>
                    <Button color="red" onClick={() => onDelete(data.id)}>
                        Delete
                    </Button>
                </Table.Cell>
            </Table.Row>
        );
    })}
</Table.Body>;
```

But having error "apiData.map()" is not a function

Comment: So, what is `apiData` at that point in the code?

Comment: Is `apiData` an array object?

Comment: I think ```api``` is not ```array```

Comment: Yea you need to console log the getData when fetching to see if it returns array.

Answer (score 0):

This is a type issue - the `apiData` state variable is not itterable. The easiest way to get the error to go away is to put a question mark before the dot:

```
<Table.Body>
    {apiData?.map((data) => {
        return (
            <Table.Row>
                <Table.Cell>{data.name}</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>{data.email}</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>
                    <Link to="/update">
                        <Button
                            color="green"
                            onClick={() =>
                                setData(data.name, data.email, data.password)
                            }
                        >
                            Update
                        </Button>
                    </Link>
                </Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>
                    <Button color="red" onClick={() => onDelete(data.id)}>
                        Delete
                    </Button>
                </Table.Cell>
            </Table.Row>
        );
    })}
</Table.Body>;
```

But this is not a real solution, you will just avoid the error instead of resolving it. The real solution is to check if `apiData` is an array before trying to `map` it. Do a `console.log` of `apiData` and post the results, please. I suspect that `apiData` is an object and what you want to map is a property of this object.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because when React renders table component, it wants to map through apiData, which didnt fetch any data yet so its empty array ( [ ] - your initial state).

You can prevent this error by adding logical AND operator:

```
{apiData && apiData.map((data) => {
```

or using optional chaining like this:

```
{apiData?.map((data) => {
```